# Dell XPS 15 9510, second NVMe drive, read-only file system on a battery

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, 21.10, samsung, nvme

I have 2021 Dell XPS 15 (9510) i7-11800H, 16 GB, 512 GB SSD, RTX 3050Ti, Windows 11 Pro.

I’ve updated the following components:

- replaced the RAM to 2x32 GB
- added a brand new Samsung 980 Pro to the second NVMe slot

On the secondary NVMe drive, I’ve installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Usually, I use Dell WD19TBS USB-C 180W to supply the power, Internet, external USB keyboard and mouse, and two monitors. When doing so, everything seems to be working perfectly for a long time whether working with Ubuntu or Windows.

However, when the laptop is running on battery, I’m observing Ubuntu freezes that happen anywhere between seconds to minutes after a reboot. The keyboard stops responding, the icons go missing, and I’m getting dropped to the terminal with the following messages appearing:

[image: __ext4_find_entry:1611 inode #12272199: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0]

`__ext4_find_entry:1611 inode #12272199: comm gmain: reading directory lblock 0`

And after a few seconds, the following start to appear:

[image: system-journald: Failed to write entry (22 items, 750 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system]

`system-journald: Failed to write entry (22 items, 750 bytes), ignoring: Read-only file system`

It seems that disconnecting the docking station usually triggers the freeze immediately. When starting from a battery, it usually takes a few minutes before everything freezes.

The only way to recover is to do a power long-press. If I do this sequence a few times - boot, wait for hang, power long-press, boot again, usually at some point the Samsung 980 Pro is no longer visible in the BIOS. I need to boot into Windows, wait a bit, reboot again, and the drive appears and it’s possible to boot to Ubuntu

What I’ve tried:

- update Ubuntu to 21.10
- update to the latest kernel: `5.13.0-41-generic`
- update all drivers, including BIOS, from Windows using Dell SupportAssistant
- update Samsung 980 Pro firmware through Samsung Magican
- enabling Full Power Mode in Samsung Magician
- check SMART report for Samsung, it’s all clear
- change GRUB params, currently they look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=off nvme_load=YES nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=250 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=0"`

  - tried also `default_ps_max_latency` values `0`, `5500`
- `fsck` from a live boot pendrive

It looks like the drive decides to go to a sleep at some point and does not wake up.

Windows works well both with docking station and battery, the Samsung NVMe is recognized by Samsung Magician.

Any hint what else can I check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows 11 on your original ssd and Ubuntu on the secondary ssd? I had Windows 10 on my original disk and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on the secondary slot and had the exact same problem(the same XPS 9510 model). I replaced the secondary ssd but still had the same issue.

**I ended up partitioning the original ssd and installed Ubuntu on the original disk**, and used the secondary ssd as a external storage space. For the past few months, it's been working fine.